# WPF: Grid with column/row margin/padding?

Tags: wpf, grid, padding, margin

**Is it easily possible to specify a margin and/or padding for rows or columns in a WPF Grid?**

I could of course add extra columns to space things out, but this seems like a job for padding/margins (it will give *much* simplier XAML). Has someone derived from the standard Grid to add this functionality?

Comment: One useful example you can find here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/107468/WPF-Padded-Grid

Comment: Kinda puzzled that this is not part of the Grid's baseline features...

Comment: As of today, demonstrated by 10 years of answers, the truth is it's not possible easily, and the best to be done (to avoid additional error prone work each time a cell is used) is to [derive Grid](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/107468/WPF-Padded-Grid) (as suggested earlier by @peter70) to add the appropriate cell padding dependency property which will control the Margin property of the cell child. This is not a long task, and then you have got a reusable control. Side comment... Grid is really a poorly designed control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own `GridWithMargin` class, inherited from `Grid`, and override the `ArrangeOverride` method to apply the margins

Comment: I don't understand why peoples give you thumbs up because it is far from being as easy as you think/describe here. Just try to do it 30 minutes and you will quickly see that your answer is unapplicable. Also think about row and column spanning

Answer (score 99):

`RowDefinition` and `ColumnDefinition` are of type `ContentElement`, and `Margin` is strictly a `FrameworkElement` property. So to your question, *"is it easily possible"* the answer is a most definite no. And no, I have not seen any layout panels that demonstrate this kind of functionality.

You can add extra rows or columns as you suggested. But you can also set margins on a `Grid` element itself, or anything that would go inside a `Grid`, so that's your best workaround for now.

Comment: OP is not attempting to set a margin on RowDefinition or ColumnDefinition. He is attempting to set a margin on the visual children of the grid, which derive from FrameworkElement.

Answer (score 93):

Use a `Border` control outside the cell control and define the padding for that:

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources >
            <Style TargetType="Border" >
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,5,5,5" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <YourGridControls/>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
            <YourGridControls/>
        </Border>

    </Grid>
```

Source:

- [Original Source](http://blogs.alankabootint.com/Posts.aspx?PostID=14#Comment14)
- [and from Way Back Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150626195237/http://blogs.alankabootint.com/Posts.aspx?PostID=14)

Comment: @RichardEverett Check the Way Back Machine: link updated in answer.

Comment: I like this answer best. It provides a solution to the original question and it's straight forward. Thanks!

Comment: This is easy and practical

Comment: When I first added this nothing changed but after running the app it updated and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 20):

You could use something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
          <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
```

Or if you don't need the TemplateBindings:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
              <Border Padding="4">
                  <ContentPresenter />
              </Border>
          </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks JayGee, however this solution is for the DataGrid - not the standard Grid control.

Comment: Clicking on the padding space doesn't select the row anymore.

Answer (score 8):

Thought I'd add my own solution because nobody yet mentioned this. Instead of designing a UserControl based on Grid, you can target controls contained in grid with a style declaration. Takes care of adding padding/margin to all elements without having to define for each, which is cumbersome and labor-intensive.For instance, if your Grid contains nothing but TextBlocks, you can do this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
</Style>
```

Which is like the equivalent of "cell padding".

Comment: does this trickle down? for instance if you have a stackpanel in a grid row,  does the stackpanel's textblock children inherit this property?

Comment: Not sure if it trickles past immediate children, but you can find out with a simple test.

Comment: @Maslow The answer is absolutely ‘Yes,’  but your wording a little misleading. There’s no “inheriting” of the `Margin` property going on, it’s that any `Style` in a `ResourceDictionary` will apply to every element of its `TargetType` everywhere ***within the entire scope*** of that dictionary’s owner element. So it’s the `Style` that trickles, not the property.

Answer (score 4):

I am surprised I did not see this solution posted yet.

Coming from the web, frameworks like bootstrap will use a negative margin to pull back rows / columns.

It might be a little verbose (albeit not that bad), it does work and the elements are evenly spaced and sized.

In the example below I use a `StackPanel` root to demonstrate how the 3 buttons are evenly spaced using margins. You could use other elements, just change the inner x:Type from button to your element.

The idea is simple, use a grid on the outside to pull the margins of elements out of their bounds by half the amount of the inner grid (using negative margins), use the inner grid to evenly space the elements with the amount you want.

**Update:**
Some comment from a user said it doesn't work, here's a quick video demonstrating: https://youtu.be/rPx2OdtSOYI

[image]

```
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-5 0"/>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>

            <Grid>
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10 0"/>
                    </Style>
                </Grid.Resources>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Btn 1" />
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Btn 2" />
                <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Btn 3" />
            </Grid>

        </Grid>

        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0 10">
            Test
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 4):

Edited:

To give margin to any control you could wrap the control with border like this

```
<!--...-->
    <Border Padding="10">
            <AnyControl>
<!--...-->
```

Comment: The OP problem is not to have a margin around the grid, but a margin around grid cells (or as actually asked around rows and columns, later contradicted by "*adding the extra columns/rows is exactly what I was attempting to avoid*" comment).

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem recently in two column grid, I needed a margin on elements in right column only. All elements in both columns were of type TextBlock.

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource OurLabelStyle}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Grid.Column" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20,0" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

I did it right now with one of my grids.

- First apply the same margin to every element inside the grid. You can do this mannualy, using styles, or whatever you like. Lets say you want an horizontal spacing of 6px and a vertical spacing of 2px. Then you add margins of "3px 1px" to every child of the grid.
- Then remove the margins created around the grid (if you want to align the borders of the controls inside the grid to the same position of the grid). Do this setting a margin of "-3px -1px" to the grid. That way, other controls outside the grid will be aligned with the outtermost controls inside the grid.

Comment: Apply the same margin to every element inside the grid seems to be the easiest way.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem while developing some software recently and it occured to me to ask WHY? Why have they done this...the answer was right there in front of me.  A row of data is an object, so if we maintain object orientation, then the design for a particular row should be seperated (suppose you need to re-use the row display later on in the future).  So I started using databound stack panels and custom controls for most data displays.  Lists have made the occasional appearance but mostly the grid has been used only for primary page organization (Header, Menu Area, Content Area, Other Areas).  Your custom objects can easily manage any spacing requirements for each row within the stack panel or grid (a single grid cell can contain the entire row object.  This also has the added benefit of reacting properly to changes in orientation, expand/collapses, etc.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <custom:MyRowObject Style="YourStyleHereOrGeneralSetter" Grid.Row="0" />
  <custom:MyRowObject Style="YourStyleHere" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

or

```
<StackPanel>
  <custom:MyRowObject Style="YourStyleHere" Grid.Row="0" />
  <custom:MyRowObject Style="YourStyleHere" Grid.Row="1" />
</StackPanel>
```

Your Custom controls will also inherit the DataContext if your using data binding...my personal favorite benefit of this approach.

Comment: What you’ve attempted to do here is create a crude version of the WPF `ListView` control in `GridView` mode, but with no provision for making all the “RowObjects” share the same column width. In reality, it no longer has much to do with a Grid.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to add fixed width rows and columns to act as the padding / margin you are looking for.

You might also consider that you are constrained by the size of your container, and that a grid will become as large as the containing element or its specified width and height. You could simply use columns and rows with no width or height set. That way they default to evenly breaking up the total space within the grid. Then it would just be a mater of centering your elements vertically and horizontally within you grid.

Another method might be to wrap all grid elements in a fixed with single row & column grid that has a fixed size and margin. That your grid contains fixed width / height boxes which contain your actual elements.

Comment: Thanks Adam, however adding the extra columns/rows is exactly what I was attempting to avoid. I simply want to reduce my markup and being able to specify a margin or padding would help with this.

Comment: You only have to define the extra columns and rows, not add the mark up for them. For example, if you want to add N width between columns for 3 columns, you would have 5 column definitions. The first would be auto width, and the next fixed, then auto, then fixed, then auto. Then only assign columns 1, 3 and 5 to actual content elements. I see your point about the extra column markup, but unless you've got hundreds of elements, that seems trivial to me. your call though. Also, have you tried using a stack panel of stack panels with the margins set?

Comment: For my case adding a "splitter/margin" column was by far the cleanest and easiest. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Though you can't add margin or padding to a Grid, you could use something like a Frame (or similar container), that you can apply it to.

That way (if you show or hide the control on a button click say), you won't need to add margin on every control that may interact with it.

Think of it as isolating the groups of controls into units, then applying style to those units.

Answer (score 0):

As was stated before create a GridWithMargins class.
Here is my working code example

```
public class GridWithMargins : Grid
{
    public Thickness RowMargin { get; set; } = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10);
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        var basesize = base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeSize);

        foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
            var pos = GetPosition(child);
            pos.X += RowMargin.Left;
            pos.Y += RowMargin.Top;

            var actual = child.RenderSize;
            actual.Width -= (RowMargin.Left + RowMargin.Right);
            actual.Height -= (RowMargin.Top + RowMargin.Bottom);
            var rec = new Rect(pos, actual);
            child.Arrange(rec);
        }
        return arrangeSize;
    }

    private Point GetPosition(Visual element)
    {
        var posTransForm = element.TransformToAncestor(this);
        var areaTransForm = posTransForm.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
        return areaTransForm;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:GridWithMargins ShowGridLines="True">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
            <Rectangle Fill="Green" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
            <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </local:GridWithMargins>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Throws System.ArgumentException: 'Width must be non-negative.'

actual.Width -= Math.Min(actual.Width, RowMargin.Left + RowMargin.Right);

actual.Height -= Math.Min(actual.Height, RowMargin.Top + RowMargin.Bottom);

Comment: With Jamie's fix, it runs, but still doesn't do what it ought to. With row height and column width set to Auto, it does the wrong thing in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

in uwp (Windows10FallCreatorsUpdate version and above)

```
<Grid RowSpacing="3" ColumnSpacing="3">
```

Comment: This also applies with `Xamarin.Forms`.

Comment: UWP != WPF... Why do comments need to be 15 characters long (rhetorical question).

Comment: ​14 chars here.

Answer (score -9):

Sometimes the simple method is the best. Just pad your strings with spaces. If it is only a few textboxes etc this is by far the simplest method.

You can also simply insert blank columns/rows with a fixed size. Extremely simple and you can easily change it.

Comment: Probably because it's not a very good method. Using spaces might be the "easy way out", but it's more of a hack actually. It's not precise, it might (and probably will) render differently and unreliably on monitors with a different scaling and you have no control over the exact amount of space you create. Inserting blank columns/rows will make a mess of your grid...